# Reset Queryable State

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm working on writing a test for my Flink system.  I want to pump data through my topology, query the state, and then reset my test.  Are there any management capabilities for Queryable state such as the ability to reset/delete current state so that I can clear my state between test runs?  I haven't found any in the docs, but I'm hoping I just missed something.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flink's queryable state client only allows you to read the state. The write path is the data flowing in your topology. Thus, there is currently now way to use the queryable state client to write state information.

What you can do is to inject a special event in your stream which is detected by your operator and upon receiving it will clear the state.